# Load function from support folder cypress

Tags: cypress, end-to-end

In my support folder I have a folder called action. In there is a file calles login-action.js. The code in this file looks like this:

```
class LoginActions{   
     login(usernameField, passwordField, username, password) {
        cy.get(usernameField).first().type(username);
        cy.get(passwordField).last().type(password);
     }
    }
    export default new LoginActions();
```

Now I want to use this login function in a test

```
loginActions.login('[data-test=username]', '[data-test=password]', this.user.username, this.user.password);
```

This is how I call it in the test. But somehow this is not working. It says that login is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can export new object like you are doing, I usually export only the class like this:

```
 export default LoginActions();
```

Do you import and create new object loginActions like this:

```
import LoginActions from '../../../support/pageObjects/{loginActionsPage}'
const loginActions = new LoginActions();
```

And after this you can:

```
loginActions.login('[data-test=username]', '[data-test=password]', this.user.username, this.user.password);
```

Comment: Now it says that there is no constructor. Do I need a constructor in my LoginActions class and how do I do that. I think I've never made a constructor in JavaScript/cypress

Comment: just add "export" before class LoginActions in login-action.js